# How to convert UTF-8 to SHIFT-JIS using vba

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba, utf-8, shift-jis

I am developing an application that reads from a text file and writes to a CSV file.
Since characters in the text file are UTF-8, the CSV file also contain the same characters.
Because of UTF-8, Double Byte(Japanese Character) cannot be written correctly in a CSV file.
Please explain the best way to write correct data.

Answer (score 1):

Most answers I've seen are work arounds, doing it manually in Google Docs or NotePad ++ or similar. The link I give offers many suggestions which may or may not suffice. The one answer by Eric may be the most useful:

> ... I tried saving the xlsx file to xls first, then to csv. It actually worked.

Sadly, one of the answers there simply writes

> I was not able to find a VBA solution for this problem on Mac Excel. There simply seemed to be no way to output UTF-8 text.

[Source and more options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221176/excel-to-csv-with-utf8-encoding)

You may be able to do this in CSV, then write a script to convert it in NotePad++ but it looks like there may have to be some manual work.